# Help with syntax trees

Tags: grammar, syntax-trees

I am having trouble creating a syntax tree for the following sentence:

Ginny thinks Harry is dreamy.

"Harry is dreamy" is clearly a sentence. However, I am confused what "is" should be. I think it should be a verb, but then that would mean "is dreamy" would be a verb phrase. However, I've learned that verb phrases cannot have adjectives and "dreamy" seems to be a adjective rather than an adverb.

Comment: Verb phrases can have predicate adjectives (like _be dreamy_), and predicate nouns (like _be a doctor_), as well as predicate verbs. (Verbs are the prototype predicate so we don't hafta call them "predicate verbs".) Non-verbal predicates require an auxiliary _be_ to carry the inflection (that's where the _is_ comes from). The clause _Harry is dreamy_ is a tensed complement clause (_that_ is the complementizer, which may be deleted in this case), and it's the direct object of _thinks_. I.e, it's a noun phrase that is a clause.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about it's about help with syntax trees.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about drawing syntax trees for specific sentences.

Answer (score 1):

In doubt you can use the [online Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp):

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (NNP Ginny))
    (VP (VBZ thinks)
      (SBAR
        (S
          (NP (NNP Harry))
          (VP (VBZ is)
            (ADJP (JJ dreamy))))))
    (. .)))
```

And view the parse tree with some [Syntax Tree Editor](http://www.ductape.net/~eppie/tree/download.html):

[image]